# Selection parameters of a X & Y rated capacitors

Tags: capacitor, basic

In a capacitor drop supply, X rated capacitors are responsible for dropping the AC voltage across them. I've been looking at why only X rated capacitors are used. After spending some time searching the internet, I found that X rated capacitors are connected in series (line to line) with the circuit, while Y rated capacitors are connected in parallel (line to ground).

The X rated capacitor is designed for 250, 400, 600 VAC. The effective impedance (Z), rectance (X) and the mains frequency (50 – 60 Hz) are the important parameters to be considered while selecting the capacitor. The reactance (X) of the capacitor (C) in the mains frequency (f) can be calculated using the formula:

$$ X = \frac{1}{2 \pi fC} $$

So at 0.22uF the reactance will be \$14.4k\Omega\$. Now the effective impedance can be calculated by using

$$ Z = \sqrt{R + X} $$

Now this Z is responsible for the dropping of the high voltage. So just because of high reactance **(is it X rated capacitor property? Correct me if I am wrong)**, is it used to drop the supply voltage? What happens if we add another capacitor in series except X rated? **Does the other one also work as a X rated capacitor?**

Comment: This site is family friendly; no X rated capacitors here...

Comment: @JYelton Means What??

Comment: Sorry SHASWAT, it's a joke referring to [motion picture  ratings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_rating).

Comment: oh great.Now I got your point.......

Comment: As far as I know the X and Y designation is the letter code for the low temperature coefficient of [Class 2 ceramic capacitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_capacitor#Class_2). I'm not sure that alone could be classified as a capacitor "rating," hence the humor.

Comment: I found something that provide little bit of Y rated cap. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56757/why-only-500vac-rating-for-this-y-capacitor

Comment: Ceramic capacitor is other thing as wikipedia says it offer high stability in case of class 1
For class 2 it offers high volumetric efficiency for decoupling, smoothing, by-pass and coupling applications.

Comment: @JYelton: Yes, the "X" and "Y" in "X7R" and "Y5V" are temperature ratings for class 2 ceramic capacitors. However, I'm pretty sure the original question is about the "X" and "Y" in "Class X" and "Class Y", which are safety ratings for mains power [plastic film EMI/RFI suppression capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_capacitor#Safety_and_EMI.2FRFI_suppression_film_capacitors) and other safety capacitors.

Answer (score 7):

X and Y *type* capacitors (as it turns out) are types of *safety* capacitors, usually for higher voltage. (The X and Y letter codes can also mean a low temperature coefficient for class 2 ceramic capacitors.)

Here are the relevant points from a [Safety Capacitor Basics document](http://www.tecategroup.com/capacitors/applications/safety_cap_files/TG_safety_capacitors.pdf) from [Tecate Group](http://www.tecategroup.com/):

- **X Capacitors** are also known as "across the line" capacitors. They are used between the "live" wires carrying incoming AC current. They're used in applications where failure of the capacitor will *not* lead to risk of electrical shock to the user.
- **Y Capacitors** are also known as "line to ground" capacitors. They are used in applications where failure of the capacitor *could* lead to the danger of electrical shock to the user, if the ground connection is lost.

Comment: So Y rated e.g can be used in EMI suppression?

Comment: Yes, page 2 of the linked document states "The function of these capacitors is to protect against surges and transients, as well as providing EMI filtering."

Comment: So if I connect another capacitor instead of X rated cap,then it can also works as same as X rated or something else happens??

Comment: Sorry SHASWAT I don't know that much about them. You might want to post that as a separate, specific question.

Comment: @SHASWAT, From an eletrical function point of view these are just capacitors. From a safety point of view these are constructed to be robust and to fail safely. Capacitors not requiring safety considerations are smaller and cheaper. X and Y capacitors will have been tested to withstand certain surges / spikes and not fail in a dangerous way.

Comment: Here is an informative link http://database.ul.com/cgi-bin/XYV/template/LISEXT/1FRAME/showpage.html?&name=FOWX2.GuideInfo&ccnshorttitle=Across-the-line+Capacitors,+Antenna-coupling+Components,+Line-bypass+Components+and+Fixed+Capacitors+for+Use+in+Electronic+Equipment&objid=1073753701&cfgid=1073741824&version=versionless&parent_id=1073753700&sequence=1

Comment: @Spoon Thanks for such a good information.But this is not the answer of my question. It works but what happens if I replace the x rated with the other capacitor..

Comment: @SHASWAT, In a "Perfect" world what happens is nothing. “Perfect” is a mains AC supply with no noise from other equipment on the supply or spikes caused by lightning or nearby welders and the like. However in a real application these disturbances in the supply are very large and will kill an ordinary capacitor in an interesting way. “interesting” is if you like things blowing up and making a fire and possible shock hazard.

Comment: @SpoonStill not getting the exact answer of my questiona

Comment: @JYelton Still not getting the exact answer of my question.I already add addition information in my question that I know, but still not getting a good response.

Comment: @JYelton Seems like everyone is OK with your answer but they didn't get what I want to ask.

Comment: @SHASWAT See my earlier comment about asking a new question that's very specific. Don't post any more comments here, because it's not where users should look for answers; just accessory information about the question or answer to which it is attached.

Comment: Can I use an Y2 capacitor in an application where they use an X?