# What is the capacitance of this Maytag fridge capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, circuits

I have this capacitor in a Maytag fridge freezer. The fan stops when the fridge is on but works when the freezer alone is on.
I am assuming the problem is the capacitor not bring able to boost power to a higher RPM.  I can not buy the same model so am looking for a replacement.
I can not recognise the capacitance specifications on the label.

It's a starter capacitor for a 230V 60/50Hz 0.05A 1W 1300 RPM motor.

It says its 2x.47u farads but then another X2. Does that make it 1.88u farads? The replacement capacitors for fridges are typically 6uF.

[image]

Comment: X2 and Y are actually ratings of safety capacitors in that module which actually consists of several capacitors and inductors (while it may look like a "capacitor" it actually says "EMI filter" right on it and has a circuit diagram).  For the capacitor aspect, please see the answer of JYelton at [Selection parameters of a X & Y rated capacitors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77726/selection-parameters-of-a-x-y-rated-capacitors)  though I'd be somewhat hesistant to conclude this is at fault unless someone with *domain experience* of similar appliances suspects so.

Comment: Motor start/run capacitors don't "boost power to a higher rpm", and what you're showing in that pic is not a capacitor anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a noise or EMI filter. Note the schematic at the bottom of the device.

The capacitor values stated on the label are what is inside the can, along with the inductive devices.

Comment: @James Gustard It is an EMI (i.e interference) filter (and quite a decent one, too). It is not a starter capacitor for your fan motor.

Comment: Thank-you are you able to explain more what the C:2x0.47uF(x2)SH means? Like why does it say 2x twice and not x4?    I assume the 2x4700pF(Y) is that there are two Y rated  capacitors of 4700 pico farads.

Comment: @James Gustard The filter says x2 twice because there are 4 capacitors in the filter; 2 of one value (4700 pF or 4.7 nF) and 2 of another value (0.47 μF or 470 nF). The significance of the X2 and Y was linked in Chris Stratton's comment.

Answer (score 1):

As variously stated the pictured component is an EMI filter not a motor start/run capacitor. There's no reason to replace this filter unless you are having problems with electrical interference associated with the fridge operation. Additionally, as noted by @brhans, a motor start capacitor doesn't "boost power to a higher rpm", it just lets a motor run at its design speed (possibly multiple speeds if the motor is designed for that).

Domestic repair questions are better off in the [Home Improvement site](https://diy.stackexchange.com/). However, is this fridge/freezer actually malfunctioning? Mention of a fan suggests this is a frost-free freezer. I have one myself (though not a Maytag) and the internal fan comes on automatically (presumably under thermostatic control) at various times. It also switches off when a door is open to stop blowing cold air into the room.

So what evidence do you have that the fan operation is actually incorrect? You stated it's working when the freezer is on so the fan motor is working. Are you sure that you are just not unfamiliar with the operation of your fridge/freezer? Did it have some previous pattern of operation that has now changed or is it new to you? Are the fridge or freezer sections failing to stay appropriately cold? Is the fridge/freezer in a location which is either unusually hot or unusually cold? (Some models need to be in a reasonable room temperature environment for their refridgeration cycle to work properly.)