# Are DC link capacitors suitable for use with AC?

Tags: capacitor

In looking for high-value (33uF) film capacitors for use with AC, I've come across a number of "DC link" capacitors. Can they be used with AC assuming their DC voltage rating exceeds the AC RMS and/or P-P?

Answer (score 2):

The DC voltage rating is the same as the ac peak voltage (not RMS or p-p) and you have to make sure you are using a non-polarized capacitor for ac signals.

Don't use polarized capacitors i.e. electrolytic or tantalum. Read the data sheets. It's a short answer but a suprisingly big subject so if in doubt post a schematic.

Comment: Fortunately film capacitors aren't polarized. And [the one I'm looking at](http://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kemet/C4AEOBW5400H3NJ/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMv1cc3ydrPrF%252b6577%252bShWohPYaPgbXPG9M%3d) is rated for 900VDC, so it should suffice (for household line use).

Answer (score 1):

Since the [datasheet for that capacitor](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/212/KEM_F3046_C4AE_RADIAL-123953.pdf) specifically says "Installation: Any position",
it is a non-polarized capacitor that is suitable for both alternating ("AC") and constant-polarity ("DC") applications.
(As I could have guessed just from the description "film capacitor").

Capacitors that are directly connected to mains voltage should meet safety and flammability standards -- these are often called "X capacitors" and "Y capacitors".
(See " [Why only 500VAC rating for this Y-capacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56757/why-only-500vac-rating-for-this-y-capacitor) "; [Wikipedia: capacitor RFI/EMI suppression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ceramic_capacitor#RFI.2FEMI_suppression); and [Wikipedia: filter capacitor mains filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/filter_capacitor#Mains_filtering) for a few details).

There are several ratings in the datasheet that you must make sure are not exceeded in your application. In particular,

DC voltage rating: for AC applications, you must pick a capacitor with a DC voltage rating greater than the the AC peak absolute voltage (typically half the AC P-P voltage). 900 VDC seems more than adequate for household line use.

Irms rating and Ipkr: you must somehow arrange things to keep the actual current less than the rated current. Or you must pick a capacitor (or some arrangement of capacitors) that has a rated current greater than the actual peak current.

Answer (score 0):

AC application to DC link capacitors raise the issue of construction in relation to electrostriction akin to magnetostriction in large transformers operating at high frequency.
Electrostriction is the movement of dielectric materials in a changing electric field which can invoke extra stresses within a capacitor. In some cases, extra stresses can occur if frequency and mechanical properties co-alighn to cause mechanical resonances which in turn can fatigue mechanical parts such as connections.
I would suggest that the capacitor manufacturerr be consulted for particular applications.